# Sikuli 1.1.4. App.open: not found in taskList after 0 secs

Tags: sikuli

Try to start app (Mojave, Sikuli 1.1.4)

```
x = App("/Applications/Calculator.app")
x.open()
```

App starts, but in message area appears error:

> [error] App.open: not found in taskList after 0 secs
>   (/Applications/Calculator.app)
>   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK93u.png)

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. 
I reported this to sikuli bug tracker, developers fixed that and released a new build (2018-12-14_08:11 (Build 148) )